# Bash Script to update file progrmatically

Tags: bash, terminal

I have a file with contents like this

```
    adv_dir=2
    ami_pro=3
```

I have a variable `$TEMP` with value `ami_pro`, I want to increase the value of `$TEMP` by 1.

Want a bash script for this.
State of file after updates

```
    adv_dir=2
    ami_pro=4
```

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/ http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: I'm so happy that I invested (a small amount of) time and effort to answer this question just so some third-parties could close it before the OP had a chance to accept an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Icky-ish, spooky indirection, but...

```
$: echo $TEMP
ami_pro
$: echo $ami_pro
4
$: (($TEMP++))  # $TEMP evals to ami_pro, which gets incremented
$: echo $TEMP
ami_pro
$: echo $ami_pro
5
$: let $TEMP++  # same, likely in any arithmetic context
$: echo $ami_pro
6
```

so...

```
TEMP=ami_pro                     # just setting in the env
grep "$TEMP=" file > $TEMP.tmp   # grap the line we need to edit
. $TEMP.tmp                      # souce it to set the var
sed -i "s/$TEMP=${!TEMP}/$TEMP=$((++$TEMP))/" file # in-place edit
```

You could skip the tempfile with `eval "$(grep "$TEMP=" file)"` but `eval` makes me itch.

The `sed` is an in-place edit of `file` using ***double-quotes*** to allow the OS to pre-process the vars before making the update.

```
TEMP=ami_pro
```

so

```
$TEMP=${!TEMP}
```

is parsed by the OS into

```
ami_pro=$ami_pro
```

Since we sources the line that said `ami_pro=3`, that gets further parsed into

```
ami_pro=3
```

then

```
$TEMP=$((++$TEMP))
```

becomes `ami_pro=$((++ami_pro))` which processes to

```
ami_pro=4
```

all `sed` gets is the result strings, so by the time `sed` *starts* parsing, what it sees is

```
s/ami_pro=3/ami_pro=4/
```

Once that edit is handled, we can break out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` for that:

```
#!/bin/bash

TMP_FILE=$(mktemp)
awk -F= "/^${TEMP}=/ {print \$1 \"=\" \$2 + 1 \"*\"; next} 1" "${1}" > ${TMP_FILE} && mv ${TMP_FILE} "${1}"
rm ${TMP_FILE}
```

Pass the file with the data as a parameter to this script.